# ¿Está bien el uso de "al + infinitivo" en este párrafo?

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales, infinitivo

¿Es correcto/está bien el uso de la forma "al + infinitivo" en el siguiente párrafo (que es una parte de un CV de traductor)?

> Al escribir en cualquier idioma, sigo las reglas de puntuación aun cuando escribo textos informales.
>
> Al escuchar programas en árabe  o al leer textos en cualquiera de mis idiomas, noto errores gramaticales y ortográficos y los corrijo mentalmente.

Comment: Bienvenida a Spanish.SE. He hecho un par de cambios en la pregunta, para mejorar el formato y hacerla más legible. También he eliminado un par de cosas acerca de las secciones del CV, que no eran realmente relevantes par la pregunta. Así es  más fácil entender qué estas preguntando.

Comment: Mariam: tienes tres cuentas diferentes (esta, [otra](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/15093/mariam) y [otra](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/15094/%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%85-%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%B0)). Considera utilizar la sección [contact us](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/contact) para pedir que se junten tus cuentas.

Answer (score 1):

Yo diría que sí. El infinitivo en español puede tener carácter nominal (por ejemplo, "Me gusta pintar", "oigo el aullar de los lobos a lo lejos") o verbal, con sujeto explícito y complemento (por ejemplo "al hacer yo la colada").

"Al + infinitivo" puede expresar muchas cosas:

- Significado temporal: "Al salir de casa, me di cuenta de que me había olvidado las llaves"
- Causa: "Al no haber helado de chocolate, pedí uno de vainilla"

En esta caso

> **Al escribir** (yo) sigo las reglas de puntuación

entiendo que tiene el significado temporal, ya que es un equivalente a "cuando"

> **Cuando escribo** (yo) sigo las reglas de puntuación